# fuzzysearch and google analytics

Tags: 6, search, google-analytics, google-search-console

I am using fuzzysearch module on Drupal 6, and his integration with Google Analytics. Regular google analytics query is working if I put query such `search/node`.
I've tried query like `fuzzysearch/results` but that one gives 0 results in google analytics?
Do i have to enable something else in my Drupal 6 `admin/settings/fuzzysearch/` or fuzzysearch is not compatible with google analytics?
I am using webmaster tools for Google analytics integration, where I place query.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Not an answer but I don't see anything to indicate that there is a working integration. Even if there were I'd say you're unlikely to find an answer here since Fuzzy Search module has about 2K installs and hasn't been updated in 2 years. Just saying.

Comment: @othermachines Yeah. and only related post I found is this one : https://www.drupal.org/node/1250838 . If you have any other indication where i can look or suggestion to try, i am more than willing to listen and try, since majority of my sites is using fuzzysearch module for D6.
Thanks!